# Cannot invoke initializer for type Height with no arguments

Tags: swift, properties, structure, observers

I'm going through Apple's App Development With Swift iBook and it's been pretty smooth sailing until the structs chapter, specifically during the property observers section. I'm tasked with checking unit conversions.

```
struct Height {
    var heightInInches: Double {
        willSet(imperialConversion) {
            print ("Converting to \(imperialConversion)")
        }
        didSet {
            if (heightInInches == (heightInCentimeters * 0.393701)) {
                print ("Height is \(heightInInches)")
            }
        }
    }
    var heightInCentimeters: Double {
        willSet(metricConversion) {
            print ("Converting to \(metricConversion)")
        }
        didSet {
            if (heightInCentimeters == (heightInInches * 2.54)) {
                print ("Height is \(heightInCentimeters)")
            }
        }
    }
    init(heightInInches: Double) {
        self.heightInInches = heightInInches
        self.heightInCentimeters = heightInInches*2.54
    }

    init(heightInCentimeters: Double) {
        self.heightInCentimeters = heightInCentimeters
        self.heightInInches = heightInCentimeters/2.54
    }
}

let newHeight = Height()
newHeight.heightInInches = 12
```

From the book and Swift documentation, I think this should work. But I get an error message stating:

> "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Height' with no arguments."

1. What does this mean and what am I misunderstanding?
2. How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: @Shades is correct. In this scenario, you can consider `Height` to behave just like a `Class`. Since you've defined two inits - `init(heightInIches:)` and `init(heightInCentimeters:)` - you cannot "instantiate" `newHeight` like that. (I'd also add that you can use *either*, but your second line of code suggests you want the first init.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your one line at the bottom should be:

```
 let newHeight = Height(heightInInches: 12)
```

---

`heightInInches` is the argument you are passing to the `init` method.

Comment: Ok! I entered that and it seems to work, however the strings ("Converting to...) are not printing to the console. I only get the number 20 back.

Comment: @MichaelFarris Did you see the note in the book (emphasis mine): *"The willSet and didSet observers of superclass properties are called when a property is set in a subclass initializer, after the superclass initializer has been called. **They are not called while a class is setting its own properties, before the superclass initializer has been called**."*